# Conditional formatting using pyformat

Tags: python, string

Given some variable

```
flag = True
x = "hello"
y = "world"
```

I would like to print the following string:

`"hello world"` if `flag is True` or `"hello 'world'"` if `flag is False`.
This could be done using the following statement:

```
print("{} {}".format(x, y if flag else "'{}'".format(y)))
```

The question is, can such a conditional format be specified directly using pyformat? I.e. is it possible to specify different format strings depending on some variable?

One solution might be to do two formats:

```
'{{}} {}'.format("{}" if flag else "'{}'").format(x, y)
```

But this makes it very hard to read as you have to escape the not replaced formats in the first string.

Comment: You can clean it up alot by using `f`: `print(f"{x} {y}" if flag else f"{x} '{y}'")`

Comment: I do not fully get the question. Are you looking for `print(f"{' '.join([x,y]) if flag else y}")`?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for this `"{} {}".format(x, y if flag is True else repr(y))`?

Comment: To answer your question: No, you cant have a 'conditional format'

Comment: your first solution is just fine, you can put the logic in a function if you need to repeat this many times, e.g. `def f(x,y flag): print("{} {}".format(x, y if flag else "'{}'".format(y))))`

Comment: @Artog oh, the f-strings look very good! Think I have to use them more often :)

Comment: Just be aware that they need python 3.6 for them to be available :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I like @schwobaseggl's solution alot, I feel that you're better of just doing a proper `if`:

```
if flag:
    print(f"{x} {y}")
else:
    print(f"{x} '{y}')
```

This will make your code much more readable and maintainable. Otherwise it feel's like you're just trying to hide away the if and making spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python 3.6 or greater, you can use f'strings: `print(f"{x} {y}" if flag else f"{x} '{y}'")`.
More info: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to select different format strings like that. In your concrete case, you could be more concise with some trickery:

```
("{} '{}'", "{} {}")[flag].format(x, y)
# 'hello world'
flag = False
("{} '{}'", "{} {}")[flag].format(x, y)
# "hello 'world'"
```

In general, a `dict` mapping of possible values of the controlling variable to their corresponding format strings would be simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> print("{x} {flag}{y}{flag}".format(x=x,y=y, flag= "" if flag else "'"))
hello world
>>> flag = False
>>> print("{x} {flag}{y}{flag}".format(x=x,y=y, flag= "" if flag else "'"))
hello 'world'
```